# Primary Key violation in spring batch

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the following error in spring batch. Any advice?

```
[ 2016-02-23 17:10:00,255 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#4_Worker-1] core.JobRunShell.run():211  ERROR]: Job DEFAULT.priceDriverJobDetailNew threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'execute' on target class [class deshaw.munshi.reconcilers.position.price.PriceDriver] failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A1DD065E0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (11).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A1DD065E0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (11).
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:331)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:112)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A1DD065E0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (11).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A1DD065E0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (11).
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:975)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:105)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:124)
    at deshaw.munshi.reconcilers.position.price.PriceDriver.execute(PriceDriver.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:322)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A1DD065E0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'posrec.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (11).
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:916)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to corrupt value in ukey table of spring which is used to generate job_id, when a job is launched.
So job description persistence is failing in database.